# emulate keyboard press using javascript in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, emulation, keyboard-events, sendkeys

how I can send keys programatically using javascript in chrome ?

I have tried this:

```
x = document.getElementById("input");

x.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'keyCode':65, 'code': 'KeyA', 'key': 'a'}));
x.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {'keyCode':97, 'charCode': 97, 'code': 'KeyA', 'key': 'a'}));
x.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {'keyCode': 65, 'code': 'KeyA', 'key': 'a'}));
```

but the input dont change the value, any help ?

Comment: Are you just trying to change the value?  Or do you specifically want to do it by emulating a keypress?

Comment: I need specifically emulate the keypress

Comment: Can you explain why?  This seems like the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: If this is for some sort of E2E testing, you might want to check out selenium or nightmare. Dave is right, though. If you start by providing some context on your problem, it will be much easier for others to provide a solution.

Comment: I'm build a chrome extension, to automatically send a message, but the send button of the aplication only enable if a key is pressed, I tried enable the button using a code like `btn.disabled = false`, it's works, but when I send `btn.click()` it doesn't work, however when I press a key using the keyboard works

Comment: selenium is a good ideia, but I can't use this right now